# Validate array inputs using laravel-jsvalidation

Tags: jquery, laravel, jsvalidation

Hi Im trying to validate an array inputs like this.

```
{!!Form::open()!!}
   <input type="text" name="value1[]">
   <input type="text" name="value1[]">
  {!! Form::submit('submit') !!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

This is my controller

```
   $rules = [
              'value1[]' => 'required|array',

         ];

   $data = $request->all()

   $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. How do you validate an input fields in laravel using laravel jsvalidation? This is the package I am using https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/issues/174

Thanks,

Comment: do just want to validate if `value1` is array or not ? Or you want to validate individual elements inside the array `value1`

Comment: Actually, Im trying to validate if value1 is not empty. I want to validate individual elements inside the array.

Comment: Please do not use the jQuery Validate tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$rules = [
              'value1.*' => 'required',

         ];
```

Reference, [validating array inputs in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays)

### Update:

```
$rules = [
              'value1' => 'array|required',

         ];
```

Comment: @Atashi if this solves your issue, you can select it as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. If I tried to validate this, using $validator->fails(), it always say true. Whether there is value or null, it always fail.

Comment: do you know the structure of value1 array?

Comment: is it like this > `value1[index][index]` or `value1[index][key]`, here index means number and key means any string

Comment: As you can see on my html, the name of the element is name="value[]", this is dynamically created,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Form Request Class and catch using

`$this->request->get('items')`

with that you can loop through your array inputs.

Here is a link that might Help you :

https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/